# mongodb update failes on express session

Tags: mongodb, express, session-state, passport.js

I am using passportjs for authentication. I am using mongodb to store express sessions. The document that gets saved contains 3 fields _id, session, expires.

When I try to update the document using mongoose it does not. It does however find the document but does not update.

Would there be any lock on the document? When I try to update from mongo console it does...

Please help.

here is my code:

```
        var conditions = { '_id' :  req.sessionID};
        var update = { $set: { 'ip': '111.11.111.1112' }};

        Sessions.update(conditions, update, function (err, res) {
            if (err) return callback("FAILED");

            return callback("SUCCESS"); 
        });
```

This is my schema.....

```
  var mongoose    = require('mongoose');

  // define the schema for our user model
  var sessionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       _id             : String,
       session         : String,
       ip              : String,
       expires     : String
  });


// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('sessionsIP', sessionsSchema, 'sessionsIP');
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK added my code

Comment: @JohnnyHK - I did mention that in my schema though. I added my schema code as well.

Comment: Can you specify the err that is coming from update fail, just console.log(err)

Comment: may I know why are you overriding `_id` ? That is the default primary key mongodb uses and it should really be an ObjectID, not a string